# "Error analyzing app version" when uploading to App Store Connect from XCode organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Since today, I cannot upload to App Store Connect my application packages anymore. I get the following error message from XCode organizer:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what this is about?

I tried changing the app version and build number several times but it did not solve it. I also do not have more information when I click "show logs".

It looks like a App Store Connect issue but does any one of you guys have the issue?

Comment: I tried different network connexions (4g, wifi, ...) and it still happen anyway...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599#705599021

Comment: Yes, also got the same issue today, but no solution as of now.

Comment: Same here today.

Comment: I've turn off everything (mac , modem , Xcode , logout from account ) and it's work.

Comment: I've been having this issue for the last hour, the logs have no errors. I kept retrying the request and eventually it progressed past "Analyzing app version" and I was able to upload my app...

Comment: I think you don't have to do something, just wait apple to fix server.

Comment: Waited it out - App Store Connect issue.

Comment: OK guys, thank you for your feedbacks. It's back to normal this morning.